# Data not rendering on the full blog page using React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, wordpress, react-native

I have done a small project so far on React Native, connecting its data source to Wordpress REST API and rendering its content on the display. There are three screens, AppBody.js - AppBodyData.js and ReadMore.js

AppBody.js and AppBodyData.js is working fine as expected, however ReadMore.js is throwing attached error.

**Error screenshot**
[image: Error screenshot]

In ideal case scenario, I would like to print the data of specific blog's content on the ReadMore page which was clicked on the AppBody blog roll feed, following is the code I have done so far;

```
    ===========AppBody===========
    // ########## Import Dependencies Here ##########
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
    import { Container, Header, Content, Card, CardItem, Left, Thumbnail, Body, Button, Icon, Right } from 'native-base';

    // ########## Import Screens Here ##########

    // ########## Import Components Here ##########
    import AppBodyData from './AppBodyData.js';

    export default class AppBody extends Component {

      constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
          data: []
        }
      }

      getData() {
        return fetch('https://vint.azurewebsites.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({ data: responseJson }, () =>console.log(this.state.data));
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <Container style={{
            marginTop: 60
          }}>
            <AppBodyData data={this.state.data} />
          </Container>
        );
      }
    }


    ===========AppBodyData===========
    // ########## Import Dependencies Here ##########
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
    import { Content, Container, Card, CardItem, Left, Thumbnail, Body, Right, Button, Icon } from 'native-base';
    import HTMLView from 'react-native-htmlview';
    import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

    // ########## Import Screens Here ##########

    // ########## Import Components Here ##########

    export default class AppBodyData extends Component {
        render() {

            let articles = this.props.data.map(function (articleData, index) {
                return (
                    <Card style={{ flex: 0 }}>
                        <CardItem>
                            <Left>
                                <Thumbnail source={require('../img/VintHub.png')} />
                                <Body>
                                    <Text>{articleData.title.rendered}</Text>
                                    <Text note>{articleData.date}</Text>
                                </Body>
                            </Left>
                        </CardItem>
                        <CardItem>
                            <Body>
                                <Image source={require('../img/world.jpg')} style={{
                                    width: 330, height: 150
                                }}/>
                                <HTMLView value={articleData.excerpt.rendered} />
                            </Body>
                        </CardItem>
                        <CardItem>
                            <Left>
                                <Button transparent onPress={Actions.readmore} textStyle={{ color: '#87838B' }}>
                                    <Text>Read more...</Text>
                                </Button>
                            </Left>
                        </CardItem>
                    </Card>
                )
            });

            return (
                <View>
                    {articles}
                </View>

            );
        }
    }

    ===========ReadMore===========
    // ########## Import Dependencies Here ##########
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Text, Image } from 'react-native';
    import { Container } from 'native-base';
    import HTMLView from 'react-native-htmlview';

    // ########## Import Screens Here ##########

    // ########## Import Components Here ##########
    import { aticle, articleData } from '../components/AppBody.js';

    export default class AppHeader extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <Container>
                    <HTMLView value={articleData.content.rendered} />
                </Container>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: import { aticle, articleData }  where are this meathods??

Comment: i think because of this only it is showing error...write method and then check it.

Comment: These are being imported from AppBodyData.js file, so that I could use them in the next screen which is ReadMore.

Comment: but the path you have given is not getting these methods...thats why you are getting this error.